# Persistence syntax

Tags: phrases

"Despite my supervisor's persistance in applying to the x, I applied to the y". Is this syntax correct? I want to say that he desperately wanted me to apply to one thing but I applied to another instead

Comment: Not really.  The sentence, as you have it in the question, suggests that the supervisor kept applying to the x. It would be better as *despite my supervisor's **insistence I apply** to the x, I applied to the y*. If you really have to use *persistence*, it would have to be something like *despite my supervisor's persistence in **trying to convince me to apply** to the x, I applied to the y*.

Answer (score 2):

*Insistence* may be a better choice than *persistence*. The reason is that to persist means to continue to do something despite opposition or hardship, as in, "Everyone said the plants wouldn't grow but he continued to water them every day and eventually, his persistence paid off."

*Insist*, on the other hand, simply means to firmly state one's desire or preference, which seems to fit your case better.

> Despite my supervisor's insistence that I apply to the x, I applied to the y.

If you really want to use *persist*, you could do so by describing a specific action taken by the supervisor.

> Despite my supervisor's persistent demands that I apply to the x, I still applied to the y.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is *insistence*, not *persistence,* from the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=insistence):

> insist
>
> v. insisted, insisting, insists
>
> v.intr.
>
> To be resolute or firm in a demand or course: *I insist on paying my
> share of the expenses*.
>
> v.tr.
>
> To assert or demand (something) firmly or persistently: *We insist that
> you stay for dinner.*
>
> insistence, insistency n.
>
> insister n.
>
> insistingly adv.

Both the verb and noun form take a declarative content clause:

> Despite my supervisor's insisting (that) I apply to x
>
> Despite my supervisor's insistence (that) I apply to x

Comment: Thank you all so much. I will write "Despite my supervisor's insistence that I should apply to the x"